# Copy value to multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have one column of values in the master sheet to copy to multiple sheets in a specific cell. Each cell value is copied to each sheet once and is repeated over 625 times. I have one column of values (A2 to A626) in the master sheet to copy to multiple sheets in a specific cell. A2 is copied to sheet 2, cell R4. This is repeated until A626 is copied to sheet 626, cell R4. The sheet containing the A2 to A626 data is "unique"

I have lifted this code from another site and it did not work to my expectation.
Sub copyPasteData()
    Dim strSourceSheet As String
    Dim strDestinationSheet As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

```
strSourceSheet = "Unique"

Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select

Range("A2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
Selection.Copy
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("R")
Cells(lastRow + 1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Comment: Please add some code that explains what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided very little details, so I will give you some general tips.

To access (set or get) the value of specific cell from specific sheet you can use following syntax:
`Worksheets("sheetName").Cells(row, col).Value` (`row` and `col` are integers, specifying row and column of a cell), so in order to paste the value to cell B3 from sheet "Sheet2" from cell C4 from sheet "Sheet1" you should write:
`Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 3).Value`.

Moreover, you can access sheet using integers (1 - first sheet, etc.) instead of names, this way you can use loops to go through every sheet:

`Worksheets(i).Cells(row, col).Value`, where `i`, `row`, `col` are integers.

After consulting with OP, the code should look like:

```
Sub CopyToMultipleSheets()
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 626
    'cell A2 will be referenced to as Cells(2, 1).Value
    'generally Ai cell is Cells(i, 1)
    'R4 cell is Cells(4, 18)
    Worksheets(i).Cells(4, 18).Value = Worksheets("unique").Cells(i, 1).Value

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Michal. As I am a beginner in macro, can you help me with the code ?

Comment: Hi Michal,I have one column of values (A2 to A626) in the master sheet to copy to multiple sheets in a specific cell. A2 is copied to sheet 2, cell R4. This is repeated until A626 is copied to sheet 626, cell R4. Thank you:)

Comment: I have all 626 sheets created and named by the values in A2 to A626.

Comment: Hi Michal, What has happened is the value from column A2 to A626 did not get copied but number value 2 to 626 gets copied.                    The sheet containing the A2 to A626 data is "unique"

Comment: The sheet containing the A2 to A626 data is "unique"

Comment: Thank you very much, the code now works as per required.